# Google Apps Script: Amazon SP-API Add parameters to the request

Tags: amazon-web-services, api

I'm trying to add additional parameters to my call to Amazon Selling Partner API.

The calls I'm doing at the moment is point at [Amazon Get Orders](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/references/orders-api/ordersV0.md)

I'd like to add two parameters: `MarketplaceIds`(required, array) and `OrderStatuses`(optional, string; e.g.: "Shipped").

My question is:

- shall this go only as part of the request or it also impacts on the canonical request?
- and how to implement it?

This is my code so far:

```
function GetOrders(){
  var access_token = AccessToken();
  //Time variables
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var isoDate = currentDate.toISOString();
  var isoString = isoDate.replace(/-/g, "").replace(/:/g, "").replace(/(\.\d{3})/, "");
  var yearMonthDay= Utilities.formatDate(currentDate, 'GTM-5', 'yyyyMMdd');

  //API variables
  var end_point = 'https://sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com';

  //Credential variables
  var aws_region = "eu-west-1";
  var service = "execute-api";
  var termination_string = "aws4_request";

  //CanonicalRequest = httpRequestMethod + '\n' + CanonicalURI + '\n' + CanonicalQueryString + '\n' + CanonicalHeaders + '\n' + SignedHeaders + '\n' + HexEncode(Hash(RequestPayload));
  //CanonicalRequest components:
  var httpRequestMethod = 'GET';
  var canonicalURI = '/orders/v0/orders';
  var canonicalQueryString = '?marketplaceId=A1PA6795UKMFR9';
  var canonicalheaders = 'host:' + "sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com" + '\n' + 'user-agent:' + 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Apps-Script; beanserver; +https://script.google.com; id: UAEmdDd-KyWEWcR137UzUzWb1fu3rUgNviHA)' + '\n' + 'x-amz-access-token:' + access_token + '\n' + 'x-amz-date:' + isoDate;
  var signedheaders = 'host;user-agent;x-amz-access-token;x-amz-date';//;user-agent & host; al comienzo
  var requestPayloadHashed = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_256, "");
  requestPayloadHashed = requestPayloadHashed.map(function(e) {return ("0" + (e < 0 ? e + 256 : e).toString(16)).slice(-2)}).join("");

  //Building the canonical request
  var canonical_string = httpRequestMethod + '\n' + canonicalURI + '\n' + "marketplaceId=A1PA6795UKMFR9" + '\n' + canonicalheaders + '\n\n' + signedheaders + '\n' + requestPayloadHashed;//UPDATED

  var canonical_signature = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_256, canonical_string);
  canonical_request = canonical_signature.map(function(e) {return ("0" + (e < 0 ? e + 256 : e).toString(16)).slice(-2)}).join("");

  //CredentialScope = Date + AWS region + Service + Termination string;
  //StringToSign = Algorithm + \n + RequestDateTime + \n + CredentialScope + \n + HashedCanonicalRequest;
  var credential_scope = yearMonthDay + '/' + aws_region + '/' + service + '/' + termination_string;
  var string_to_sign = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" + '\n' + isoString + '\n' + credential_scope + '\n' + canonical_request;
  var kSecret = ACCESS_KEY;
  var kDate = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(yearMonthDay, "AWS4" + kSecret);
  var kRegion = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(toBytes(aws_region), kDate);
  var kService = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(toBytes(service), kRegion);
  var kSigning = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(toBytes(termination_string), kService);

  var signature = hex(Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(toBytes(string_to_sign), kSigning));

  var options = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'headers': {
      //'host': end_point,
      'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Apps-Script; beanserver; +https://script.google.com; id: UAEmdDd-KyWEWcR137UzUzWb1fu3rUgNviHA)',
      'x-amz-access-token': access_token,
      'x-amz-date': isoDate,
      'Authorization': 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=' + ACCESS_ID + '/' + credential_scope + ', SignedHeaders=' + signedheaders + ', Signature=' + signature,
    },
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  }
  var getOrders = UrlFetchApp.fetch(end_point + canonicalURI + canonicalQueryString, options);
  Logger.log(getOrders);
}
```

I already have a variable `marketplaceId` on my canonicalQueryString parameter but using it as it is I'm getting the following response:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
     "message": "Missing or invalid request parameters: [MarketplaceIds]",
     "code": "InvalidInput"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Were you able to fix it? Can you help me with the STS Token? I am stuck there.

Answer (score 1):

Change
var canonicalQueryString = '?marketplaceId=A1PA6795UKMFR9';
to
var canonicalQueryString = '?MarketplaceIds=A1PA6795UKMFR9';